# How to restore ssh key in aws auto scale group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We lost the ssh key for aws instances in auto scaling group and need suggestions in restoring the ssh keys

Comment: Create a new launch config with a new key and apply it to the ASG to replace the instances with ones that have the correct key.

Comment: Ideally you would never need SSH access to autoscaled EC2 instances.